# Handling :js format with mobylette in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using `mobylette` gem to manage `:mobile` format views. Seems to be working fine except for this:

I have a controller that renders a javascript file (`/app/views/photos/index.js.erb`).

```
class Photos < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js
  def index 
    ...
  end
end
```

If I access from the desktop to `/photos` or `/photos.js` seems to be working fine (I see the .js output) but If I access from a mobile device Im getting the following error

```
Template is Missing
Missing template photos/index, application/index with locale {:locale => [:en], :formats => [:mobile], :handlers => [:erg,:coffee,:haml]}. Searched in: *"/Users/user/site/app/views" * "/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.5.2/app/views" * "/Users/user/site/app/views"
```

I have the following code in `application_controller.rb`

```
before_filter :set_request_format, :set_format_fallbacks

def set_request_format
  if is_mobile_request? && request.format.to_s == "text/html"
      request.format = :mobile
  elsif is_mobile_request? && request.format.to_s == "text/javascript"
      request.format = :mobilejs
  end
end

def set_format_fallbacks
  if request.format == :mobile
    self.formats = [:mobile, :html]
  elsif request.format == :mobilejs
    self.formats = [:mobilejs, :js]
  end
end
```

And this in `/config/initializers/mime_types.rb`

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
Mime::Type.register_alias "text/javascript", :mobilejs
```

For some reason the `[:mobile]` format is still being rendered when it should be `:js` instead (since `:mobilesjs` is not present).

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? Could you please explain how? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the prettiest of solutions, but I did not find a mobylette-supported way to do it either.
I used a similar way, but could not use 'request.format' in your before_filter, I had to use 'request.filtered_parameters["format"]' instead.
Still looking for the pretty version.

Answer (score 0):

```
index.js.erb
```

It change to

```
index.erb
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer is unclear and lacking detail. What's removing the `.js` and why? Is it a good thing or a bad thing? How should OP resolve it. An answer should do its best to provide an explanation and solution, not just some relevant information.

Comment: Pretty sure you're obliged to indicate the format of your erb file in the name. `index.js.erb` or `index.html.erb` are OK, but I have no idea what `index.erb` would do.